# Making 3 points stick on a plane / flag with wind

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

I have a flag I want to waft in the wind. I imported the shape as an SVG from Adobe Illustrator.

I converted the mesh to a curve.  It wouldn't let me make some subdivisons but it still seems to work with the cloth property.

[image: Flag set up]

When I press play, you can see the structure of the flag stops.  How can I make those last 3 points intact? Also the fill colour seems to have disappeared, do you know why and how I can bring it back?

[image: Floppy flag]

Thanks

Steve

File here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mb8jsdnjm9f1enc/flag.blend?dl=0

Comment: could you share your .blend file please?

Comment: @kranukit just updated the questions with a link - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such simple shape should be modeled directly in Blender, I see no need to import an SVG. Resulting bezier curve objects have poor topology with uneven density, unsuited for most tasks like simulations.

I'd model it manually with an even quad based topology, create a *Vertex Group* for the side closest to the post, then use a *Subdivision surface Modifier* before the *Cloth* simulation.

[image: Topology]

Use the *Pinning* option for the above *Vertex Group* and add the force field.

[image: Flag Animation]

Comment: Thanks - A great help! Going to try to learn the first bit!

Comment: Hi @Duarte, apologies I am having trouble creating 'an even quad based topology'.  I can create a curve, but it is too rigid which is why I think I understand the 'even quad based topology.  Can you direct me to where I can make that model?

Comment: It is just a simple plane subdivided. The first screenshot shows the base mesh

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, have made some progress!

Comment: Hi @Duarte Farrajota Ramos, I have tried to render this but having issues, and is very distorted. Here is a gif! https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m3FC.gif - I have been told to swap the order of the modifiers around but that gives me different results

Comment: Hi @Duarte, managed to get it sorted.  Thanks again for your help!