# Can I attach clothes with ropes for a simulation?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to create a boat sail & simulate the sail moving by the wind force

but I can't make the the clothes move the rope (or a wood stick) by the wind force like this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DQdzhTH6PA

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120119/making-3-points-stick-on-a-plane-flag-with-wind/120132#120132

Comment: I need to attach the fabric with ropes & not directly to the stick,i want to know if that possible.